# Style Android toolbar action buttons

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm using the Android Suppport Library Toolbar in my activity, and for some reason I can't seem to adjust the colour of the action buttons, as shown on the right of the following screenshot:

[image: Example]

These stubbornly remain black regardless of what I do. The toolbar is defined as follows in my layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/trip_detail_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.TopToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

The TopToolbarTheme is defined as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TopToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorNavigationBackground</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorNavigationBackground</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I can't seem to find any combination of options that style these action buttons. Is this even possible in Android?

Comment: When I've had to do this, I've just taken the icons from the [material icon set](https://design.google.com/icons/) and recoloured them. I don't think there's a way to change them using stylesheets (I could be wrong though).

Comment: I agree with @GeordieMatt: make a copy of the icons you want in your drawables and change their colors. You could also check [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) for new icons